# Is there any method to join one level past a related_name?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm repeatedly running into a data situation that I feel django probably has a shortcut for, but I can't find it...

I want to access a model one relationship beyond a queryset I selected via a related_name. It feels like there should be a one-liner for this, but the best I've figured out is:

```
for p in team.players:
   do_whatever(p.user.email)
```

Using `select_related` will precache the data, but won't actually give it to me in a usuable form.

```
team.players.select_related('user')  # still returns queryset of Players, not Users
```

It just seems like there should be some way for me to get a query_set of the associated `user`s via one call. Something like `annotate`:

```
users = team.players.annotate('user')   # doesn't work
```

Is there any method that does what I'm looking for? Or is the "for - in" loop the only way to go?

The basics of my classes (greatly simplified):

```
class Team(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()

class Player(models.Model):
   team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="players")
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="players")
   captain = models.BooleanField()
```

Is there any one-liner or optimization beyond doing a select_related followed by a for-in?

Comment: So for a `Team` you want the users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#filter) with:

```
User.objects.filter(players__team=team)
```

This will retrieve all the `User`s for which there is a `Player` object that refers to the `team`. If a `User` can be part of the team multiple times, you can use [**`.distinct()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct) to retrieve each `User` at most once:

```
User.objects.filter(players__team=team).distinct()
```